# Why compiling with C++11 is successful despite using C++14 feature?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14, compiler-warnings

GCC v6.1 (the result is the same with v5.1) successfully compiles the code below with flags `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`, but produces this warning:

```
variable templates only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct ParamMetadata {
        T min;
        T max;
};

template <class T1, class T2>
class FooMap {};

template <typename T>
// WARNING PRODUCED ON THIS LINE
extern FooMap<int, ParamMetadata<T> > metadataHashmap;

int main() {
        return 0;
}
```

Clang v3.8 produces a similar warning:

```
variable templates are a C++14 extension [-Wc++14-extensions]
```

If this is a feature only available in C++14, why does it compile with C++11 flag just fine  and I can run the executable? Shouldn't it be a fatal error?

Comment: Use `-pedantic-errors` for an error

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Sure, but how does the program manage to be built and run without the required feature?

Comment: Why do you think it runs without the required feature?

Comment: @n.m. The fact that I can execute the produced executable. Some comments in an answer to my question suggest that it doesn't run "without the required feature".

Comment: The fact that you can execute the produced executable means that it runs, period. Why you conclude that it runs without some feature or another remains unclear. If you mean the compiler message, then you are misinterpreting it. A feature is "available" when one can use it in a program that builds without diagnostic messages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The C++ standard does not have the concept of a "fatal compiler error".  Programs are either ill-formed with a diagnostic required, or ill-formed with no diagnostic required, or well-formed.

In C++, the only requirement the standard places on a ill-formed program diagnostic is to display a diagnostic<sup>1</sup>.  The contents of that diagnostic are not defined.  What else happens besides that diagnostic is not defined.

Many compilers implement extensions to the C++ standard they are told to compile against that take otherwise ill-formed programs and produce a runnable executable.  If they are compliant to a standard, the only thing they must do is print a warning message (which satisfies the diagnostic requirement of the C++ standard(s)).

In this case, it is printing a warning message that you used a C++14 feature.  It has now successfully done what the C++11 standard requires with your ill-formed program.  It also produces an executable that does what your program would do if that feature from the C++14 standard was used: it is free to do so, as the standard at this point places no restrictions on what the program does once it is an ill-formed C++11 program.

If you don't want this option, compilers often have a `warnings-as-errors` flag, and various `strict` and `pedantic` flags that block extensions to the standard they use.  Then the error will suppress the generation of the executable, and you will no longer be confused.

gcc by default assumes you actually want to compile the provided code into something, rather than act as a standard-enforcer, and only generates errors when it has no reasonable way to interpret your code as a program that probably matches your intentions.  It provides flags to switch it to a strict and pedantic mode.

---

<sup>1</sup> Amusingly, printing out a single space character satisfies the requirement to display a diagnostic.  The C++ standard can be read in pathological ways in order to generate a poor quality of implementation in your compiler: generating a hostile compiler-proof standard is not worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you so much and all who have responded to my question. What an excellent answer! I have learnt a lot about compilers today. A good thing to add (which is the practical solution to my question) is to use flag `-pendatic-errors` (in combination with `-std=c++11 -pedantic`), which will cause the compiler to throw an error when a C++14 feature is used.

Comment: " It also produces an executable that does what your program would do if it was compiled under the C++14 standard"  - only in respect to this particular feature:  there may be other parts of the program that are still compiled successfully with C++11 rules that would have been different in C++14.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing "should be a fatal error". If the compiler writes a message telling you what happened it's fulfilled its obligations.

You are now free to make a fully informed decision about whether to treat the code as having fatal error and change the code; or to treat it as if it were C++14 and go with it.

You can use the switch `-Werror` (changes the word "warning" to "error" in the message) if you feel it would help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If the program is able to run without this feature, then the implication of my question is what is instead the behaviour of `FooMap` when compiled with C++11? The "filly informed" part in your response is what would be a very useful answer.

Comment: @SpaghettiCat It's not being "run without this feature". The feature is fully compiled as if you were using `-std=c++14`. The only difference is that you get a warning.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh right.... so the compiler forces the use of `-std=c++14` when it sees code that is C++14 only? I wasn't aware of this behaviour...

Comment: @SpaghettiCat compilers typically implement a whole bunch of behaviour beyond the minimum requirement of the standard, that they feel would be useful to their developers.   In this case the compiler is saying "The C++11 standard document didn't mention this but we assume you want to use the matching C++14 feature so we'll do that for you if that's OK, yay!" .  In theory the compiler documentation should describe all of these cases but I suspect that in practice a case like this it would assume that the warning message provides sufficient documentation.

Comment: @M.M Ah I see. It's bizarre though why it would include the feature when I explicitely said I want to build a program against the C++11 standard. What's the point of allowing a user to specify the standard when that requirement will be ignored anyway? If I specify the standard and the source code doesn't meet it the code should be rejected.

Comment: @SpaghettiCat `I explicitely said I want to build a program against the C++11 standard` No, you had not. A proper way to do it is to use `-std=c++11 -pedantic-errors`. With these flags the compiler would behave as you expect.

Comment: @SpaghettiCat the requirement is not ignored.   The compiler wrote a message which means the program is rejected according to C++11. The compiler went on to do something else after rejecting the program because many people find such behaviour useful.   Nobody is forcing you to use any resulting executable.